# Tap To Play Button Flashing Stops

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a game, and for the homepage, I want the “Tap To Play” button to fade in and out. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var highscoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var taptoplay: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    flashing(buttonName: taptoplay)

    let highscore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highscore")
    highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(highscore)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func flashing(buttonName:UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse, animations: {
        buttonName.alpha = 1
        buttonName.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)

}

}
```

My problem is that the text flashes perfectly like how I want about two times, but then it just disappears, and I can’t even click on the button. In fact, I can’t click on the button even when it does flash correctly.

The button was working fine before I added this code, and it’s still all linked up properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you animated your button, the last thing you did to it was set its alpha to 0. Somehow, you need to set the alpha back to 1 after your button is finished animating, or, change the order, and set the alpha to 0 first.

EDIT: In addition, the default setting for user interaction is nil, so you need to add another option: `allowUserInteraction`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the quick reply. When I change the order it animates perfect however I can still not click on the button whilst it’s animating and then it suddenly becomes 1 alpha again and then I can press the button but it won’t animate still.

Comment: I think the way to add two options is to do this: `options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]`

Comment: I added that and I also added .repeat and now it’s working perfect!

Comment: Glad I could help :)